# Conservation of angular momentum

Tags: c#, angularjs, physics, momentum

I'm working on a 2D physics engine in C#.
I've got everything working other than resolving rotation during collisions.
I have what I thought was a solution but it causes the objects to bounce insanely high and spin at high speed.

I calculate the relative velocity of two points as follows:

```
Vector2 collisionPointVelocityA = bodyA.linearVelocity; + (bodyA.angularVelocity * collisionPointRadiusAPerpendicular);
Vector2 collisionPointVelocityB = bodyB.linearVelocity; +(bodyB.angularVelocity * collisionPointRadiusBPerpendicular);        

//Relative velocity of bodyA's with respect to bodyB's collision-point velocity
collisionPointRelativeVelocityAtoB = collisionPointVelocityA - collisionPointVelocityB;
```

I then calculate an impulse to be exerted on the project:

```
j = Vector2.Dot(-(1 + (bodyA.Restitution + bodyB.Restitution) * 0.5f) * collisionPointRelativeVelocityAtoB, collisionInfo.CollisionNormal)
        / (Vector2.Dot(collisionInfo.CollisionNormal, (collisionInfo.CollisionNormal * (bodyA.InverseMass + bodyB.InverseMass))));
```

And apply rotational force to the object like so:

```
float torque = Vector2.Dot(parameter_Force, radiusVectorNormal) * radiusVector.Length();
```

And add the torque like this:

```
angularVelocity += parameter_Torque * InverseInertia;
```

I think this causes a problem due to conservation of angular momentum but I'm stuck on how to fix it.

Comment: This question suits better at Game Development: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can probably get some inspiration from https://bepuphysics.codeplex.com/ source code.

Comment: Thanks pal, I'll ask there